# DHCP Server no answer on CentOS 6.10

Tags: centos, dhcp

I have installed dhcp (4.1.1) on Centos 6.10. I am using the following configuration:

```
#specify domain name
option domain-name "example.com";
#specify DNS server ip and additional DNS server ip
option domain-name-servers 192.168.5.40;
#specify default lease time
default-lease-time 600;
#specify Max lease time
max-lease-time 7200;
#specify log method
log-facility local7;
#Configuring subnet and iprange
subnet 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.5.50 192.168.5.200;
option broadcast-address 192.168.5.255;
#Default gateway ip
option routers 192.168.5.1;
}
```

When testing the server with dhcping from both localhost (server itself) and from a system on the network, I am receiving `no answer`.
`dhcping -s 192.168.5.40`
The output from another computer on the network (running Fedora) is:

```
# dhcping -V -s 192.168.5.40
setup
request
packet 250 bytes
01 01 06 00 fe cc 2d 5c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 63 82 53 63 
35 01 03 32 04 00 00 00 00 ff 
op: 1
htype: 1
hlen: 6
hops: 0
xid: fecc2d5c
secs: 0
flags: 0
ciaddr: 0.0.0.0
yiaddr: 0.0.0.0
siaddr: 0.0.0.0
giaddr: 0.0.0.0
chaddr: 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
sname : .
fname : .
option 53 DHCP message type
        DHCP message type: 3 (DHCPREQUEST)
option 50 Request IP address
        Requested IP address: 0.0.0.0
no answer
close
```

Additional information:
Disabling iptables makes no difference. DHCP and DNS Server are the same machine (192.168.5.40). The output of `netstat -tulpen` (on server) is as follows:

```
# netstat -tulpen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          12595      1795/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         12065      1510/named          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      496        12146      1538/redis-server 1 
tcp        0      0 192.168.5.40:53             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         12062      1510/named          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         12060      1510/named          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          12254      1589/sshd           
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      0          12597      1795/master         
tcp        0      0 ::1:953                     :::*                        LISTEN      25         12066      1510/named          
tcp        0      0 :::3306                     :::*                        LISTEN      498        12343      1668/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      0          12732      1808/httpd          
tcp        0      0 :::53                       :::*                        LISTEN      25         12055      1510/named          
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      0          12256      1589/sshd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67                  0.0.0.0:*                               0          14480      2146/dhcpd          
udp        0      0 192.168.5.40:53             0.0.0.0:*                               25         12061      1510/named          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                               25         12059      1510/named          
udp        0      0 :::53                       :::*                                    25         12054      1510/named
```

**P.S.**

Adding `authoritative` to the configuration file does not solve the issue.

Comment: Just to be sure: your DHCP server and DNS server are on the same `192.168.5.40` machine? Do you have a firewall enabled? What's the output of `netstat -tulpen` on the DHCP server?

Comment: @Lenniey updated.

Comment: You didn't set the `authoritative` directive in your conf file.

Comment: @Lenniey, updated. Does not make a difference.

Comment: What's in the logfiles?

Comment: @Lenniey [here](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/DOw-TcWi07zjE6kCSjCuHQ)'s the logs at `/var/log/messages`

Comment: Your DHCP server is working: `Jan  3 13:02:47 myserver dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 70:70:0d:0d:47:df via eth0
Jan  3 13:02:48 myserver dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.5.92 to 70:70:0d:0d:47:df (Mehrizi) via eth0
Jan  3 13:02:49 myserver dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.5.92 (192.168.5.40) from 70:70:0d:0d:47:df (Mehrizi) via eth0
Jan  3 13:02:49 myserver dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.5.92 to 70:70:0d:0d:47:df (Mehrizi) via eth0` and

Comment: `Jan  3 13:06:57 myserver dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.5.91 from 7c:2e:dd:79:9d:c3 (TARASHEH) via eth0
Jan  3 13:06:57 myserver dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.5.91 to 7c:2e:dd:79:9d:c3 (TARASHEH) via eth0`

I assume it's the client's fault: `Jan  3 13:07:46 myserver dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 0.0.0.0 from 00:00:00:00:00:00 via eth0: wrong network.
Jan  3 13:07:46 myserver dhcpd: DHCPNAK on 0.0.0.0 to 00:00:00:00:00:00 via eth0`

Comment: Also: be careful what you post in your logs...

Comment: But then I cannot browse example.com on the device that is connected to this server (directly).

Comment: Could be because of your DNS denying every query: `192.168.5.91#25786: query (cache) 'android.clients.google.com/A/IN' denied`, `client 192.168.5.40#36629: query (cache) 'mirror.premi.st/A/IN' denied`, etc.

Comment: So, I must have configured named incorrectly, haven't I?

Comment: Could be the case

Comment: @Lenniey, everything seems perfect in /etc/named.conf and /var/named/example.com.zone and /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0. [Link](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/q9zN9tGhoVX49N5Dy~FiqQ)

Comment: The named issue is a completely different question and should be posted as such, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Lenniey unfortunately, I have reached my question limit for now.

Comment: @codezombie As per the info provided so far I think DHCP service is working. Maybe is the DNS service you have to work on now. I've set up a DHCP server with your configuration and I could get an IP without a problem in CentOS7. `dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.5.50 to _MACADDRESS_ (server1) via ens37`.

Comment: @ManuelFlorian it seems the way I tested `dhcping` was wrong as it returns `no answer` even for 8.8.8.8. Actually, the problem was with firewall rules. Port 53 was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `dhcping` had nothing to do with the health of my DHCP server, rather there was a problem with my iptables rules. I checked firewall rules running `service iptables status`:

I noticed that only 80 and 443 were open on TCP. I opened them for UDP as well. I also opened 53 (DNS) by running:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

I'm not sure about the UDP part. Maybe ports would work without UDP. However, I guess what solved the problem was adding a rule for port 53.
Now, I  am able to connect a device directly to server's RJ45 port, be given an IP, and browse the website hosted on the server.

Comment: It makes sense now. Both DNS queries and DHCP need port 53/UDP to work. Glad you figured out.